# Exclude specific pattern while using sed

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I need ask a question if this possible to to with sed utility.
I have file (just a piece - 2 rows):

```
"740b3d39-7676-485a-b3d6-041f6af273e5"|"8917963"|"BDSA-2021-3803"|"CVE-2021-4102"|"BDSA"|"NEW"|""|""|""|"Chromium is vulnerable to a use-after-free (UAF) issue in the `V8` functionality.A remote attacker could trick a victim user into viewing a crafted HTML page in order to trigger the UAF flaw and cause memory corruption.**Note**: Google has reported [here](https://chromereleases.googleblog.com/2021/12/stable-channel-update-for-desktop_13.html) that they are ""aware of reports that an exploit for CVE-2021-4102 exists in the wild.""
This vulnerability is listed as exploitable by the Cybersecurity & Infrastructure Security Agency in their [Known Exploited Vulnerabilities Catalog](https://www.cisa.gov/known-exploited-vulnerabilities-catalog)."|"MEDIUM"|"6.8"|"8.6"|"6.4"|""|"HIGH"|"8.8"|"2.8"|"5.9"|"8.2"|"NETWORK"|"True"|"False"|"2021-12-17 12:59:04.779000+00:00"|"2022-12-13 14:15:49.529000+00:00"|""|""
```

I want to replace `""` with any character (for example `~`), but remain `|""`
I try to run `sed "/\|\"\"/ s/\"\"/~/g"` but this replace all into file and I need only reference of `""`

Please  advice and thanks for willing to help

```
sed "/\|\"\"/ s/\"\"/~/g"  <file_name>
```

Comment: First line end with .......wild.""

Comment: `I want to replace "" with any character (for example ~), but remain |""` Is this a goal in itself, or is it XY question? What for?

Comment: what about `|"""`? keep it as is or convert it to `|"~`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the expected output for the input you posted.

Comment: I don't understand your question. What is the meaning of "replace .... but remain", and of "only reference"?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to do, using a sed that accepts `\n` in the search and replace sections, e.g. GNU sed?

```
$ sed 's/|""/\n/g; s/""/~/g; s/\n/|""/g' file
"740b3d39-7676-485a-b3d6-041f6af273e5"|"8917963"|"BDSA-2021-3803"|"CVE-2021-4102"|"BDSA"|"NEW"|""|""|""|"Chromium is vulnerable to a use-after-free (UAF) issue in the `V8` functionality.A remote attacker could trick a victim user into viewing a crafted HTML page in order to trigger the UAF flaw and cause memory corruption.**Note**: Google has reported [here](https://chromereleases.googleblog.com/2021/12/stable-channel-update-for-desktop_13.html) that they are ~aware of reports that an exploit for CVE-2021-4102 exists in the wild.~
This vulnerability is listed as exploitable by the Cybersecurity & Infrastructure Security Agency in their [Known Exploited Vulnerabilities Catalog](https://www.cisa.gov/known-exploited-vulnerabilities-catalog)."|"MEDIUM"|"6.8"|"8.6"|"6.4"|""|"HIGH"|"8.8"|"2.8"|"5.9"|"8.2"|"NETWORK"|"True"|"False"|"2021-12-17 12:59:04.779000+00:00"|"2022-12-13 14:15:49.529000+00:00"|""|""
```

With other seds you'd replace `\n` with a backslash followed by literal newline or `'$'\n''` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

replacing `""` for example in `are ""aware`   and `wild.""` but not `|""`

```
$ sed -E 's/([^|])""/\1~/g' file
```